# sed command using chef

Tags: xml, linux, sed, chef-infra

Hi I am using sed command in chef recipe but its throwing error. But If I run just sed command on CLI it works. Any help appreciated.

My sed command is -

```
sed -i -e "/<BigSQL>/,/<\/BigSQL>/ s|<username>[0-9a-z.]\{1,\}</username>|<username>bigsql</username>|" /home/biadmin/install.xml
```

And my chef recipe is -

```
bash "change_bigsqluser" do
user "root"
code <<-EOH
sed -i -e "/<BigSQL>/,/<\/BigSQL>/ s|<username>[0-9a-z.]\{1,\}</username>|<username>bigsql</username>|" /home/biadmin/install.xml
EOH
end
```

Here is the error

```
Error executing action `run` on resource 'bash[change_bigsqluser]'
================================================================================


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20140807-4025602-160wvt2" ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unknown command: `B'
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20140807-4025602-160wvt2" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20140807-4025602-160wvt2" returned 1


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/biginsights/recipes/temp.rb

 22: bash "change_bigsqluser" do
 23: user "root"
 24: code <<-EOH
 25: sed -i -e "/<BigSQL>/,/<\/BigSQL>/ s|<username>[0-9a-z.]\{1,\}</username>|<username>bigsql</username>|" /home/biadmin/install.xml
 26: EOH
 27: end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/biginsights/recipes/temp.rb:22:in `from_file'

bash("change_bigsqluser") do
  action "run"
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  command "\"bash\"  \"/tmp/chef-script20140807-4025602-160wvt2\""
  backup 5
  returns 0
  user "root"
  code "sed -i -e \"/<BigSQL>/,/</BigSQL>/ s|<username>[0-9a-z.]{1,}</username>|<username>bigsql</username>|\" /home/biadmin/install.xml\n"
  interpreter "bash"
  cookbook_name "biginsights"
  recipe_name "temp"
end



[2014-08-07T04:25:49-07:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception

Running handlers:
[2014-08-07T04:25:49-07:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete

[2014-08-07T04:25:49-07:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-08-07T04:25:49-07:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 7.374318882 seconds
[2014-08-07T04:25:49-07:00] ERROR: bash[change_bigsqluser] (biginsights::temp line 22) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20140807-4025602-160wvt2" ----
STDOUT:
STDERR: sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unknown command: `B'
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20140807-4025602-160wvt2" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20140807-4025602-160wvt2" returned 1
[2014-08-07T04:25:49-07:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: "its throwing error" - what error? Always include details in your question that might help someone else understand the problem, if you don't understand them yourself.

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are executing just a single command and you are not using any bash features, I would use an [`execute`](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_execute.html) resource:

```rb
execute "Do some sed" do
    command "sed -i '/<BigSQL>/,/</BigSQL>/ s|<username>[0-9a-z.]{1,}</username>|<username>bigsql</username>|' /home/biadmin/install.xml"
    action :run
end
```

Comment: Hi hek2mgl , I have already done that too. Ran same command in execute target but its also throwing same error.

Comment: If it throws the *same* error, it seems that it is actually executing the older revision of the recipe. Can you bootstrap the host again or at least clean up the chef cache and check if it is working?

Answer (score 0):

Since this came up as the first result in Google, I thought I've provide an answer for completeness.

If you look in the compiled resource, the code starts off like this:

```
sed -i -e \"/<BigSQL>/,/</BigSQL>/
```

The issue is with escaping. Just change: `code <<-EOH` to `code <<-'EOH'`:

```
bash "change_bigsqluser" do
user "root"
code <<-'EOH'
sed -i -e "/<BigSQL>/,/<\/BigSQL>/ s|<username>[0-9a-z.]\{1,\}</username>|<username>bigsql</username>|" /home/biadmin/install.xml
EOH
end
```